# Twitter typeahead local dataset not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Twitter typeahead by using post at http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-typeahead.php

I have downloaded typeahead.js 0.11.1 from http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js

My HTML is

```
<body>
    <input id="test" type="text" class="typeahead tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
</body>
```

My Javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'e',
        local: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
    });
});
```

But, typeahead feature is not working.I dont see any hint in textbox while typing. Also there's no log in browser console .

Can someone please help ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: How are you including `typeahead` in your page?

Comment: you dont need `.typeahead` if you are selecting by id `$('#test')` will work

Comment: I am including typeahead like following: <script src="/appbase/assets/js/typeahead.js"></script>

I already tried $('#test').typeahead, but no luck

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/rzvnHQLe6A  working fine..

Comment: Thanks for your reply @shri. I think there's something wrong with js imports?
My sequence is
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="typeahead.js"></script>

Is there possibility of any other js overriding the event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/1jttf8y4/)**

```
var numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: [
{ num: 'one' },
{ num: 'two' },
{ num: 'three' },
{ num: 'four' },
{ num: 'five' },
{ num: 'six' },
{ num: 'seven' },
{ num: 'eight' },
{ num: 'nine' },
{ num: 'ten' }
]
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
numbers.initialize();

// instantiate the typeahead UI
$('input').typeahead(null, {
displayKey: 'num',
source: numbers.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: this Bloodhound stuff just worked fine :). No idea what it is though. Seems I need to read about it now. Thanks a ton.